# Motion sensors in hardcore

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Unless you have a spy plane up, they seem totally useless. Am I missing another use for them?

Comment: they are pretty useless in HC.

Comment: Just did some research. They work if you press start. Whats the point? Bad game design imo. :/

Comment: Hardcore games are designed to have a limited HUD.  Play standard core if you want to use Motion Sensors

Comment: Imo they should bring up the radius of the equipment up as a minimap. Quite an obvious thing to add into the game if they had thought about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are definitely useless, unless you like to pause your game constantly, which seems like a bad idea.